# XML queries XPATH/XQUERY thar returns

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, contains

I'm building my library database, that I want to query when I'm looking for a subject. This is the structure of my XML database

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ebook-database title="Engineering"> 
 <ebook title="EB-001"> 
  <reference>EB-001</reference> 
  <title>POWER INSTALLATIONS</title> 
  <level1>INTRODUCTION
  </level1>
  <level1>POWER UTILITIES
    <level2>Power cables</level2>
    <level2>Power lines</level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>HIGH VOLTAGE INSTALLATIONS
    <level2>Cable structure</level2>
  </level1>
 </ebook> 
</ebook-database>
```

I want to make an Xpath/Xquery to search for the string "cable", so that it would return me that "cable" is mentioned in the chapter(level 1) "Power utilities" and "High Voltage installations" of ebook "EB-001".

Thanks in advance,

Semir

Comment: What have you tried ? In what element should be cable found ? `<level2>` only ? Please add exact expected output of the query to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use translate function to make search case insensitive

```
//*[contains(translate(text(), 'CABLE', 'cable') ,'cable')]
```

result

```
Element='<level2>Power cables</level2>'
Element='<level2>Cable structure</level2>'
```